# Adding time and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns in MSSQL 2008 R2: `Workingdate` and `Startime`.
Due to a mistake in the design of the application starttime was not defined as date+time, but only time (e.g. `1899-12-30 16:00:00.000` for 4:00 PM)

Now, I am facing a Problem that I cannot add date and time.

Why is

```
 select convert(datetime,'2015-07-01 00:00:00.000') + convert(datetime,'1899-12-30 16:00:00.000')

2015-06-29 16:00:00.000  and not 2015-07-01 16:00:00.000
```

Thanks your help

Sorry: I found the solution: Date comes from VBA and the first day is 1899-12-30 and not 1900-01-01 as in SQL  !!! Therefore I have to add +2  !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select dateadd(second, 
                datepart(hour,'1899-12-30 16:00:00.000') * 3600 + 
                datepart(minute,'1899-12-30 16:00:00.000') * 60 + 
                datepart(second,'1899-12-30 16:00:00.000'),
                '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000')
```

The idea is to use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to add the needed time in seconds to your base date (`2015-07-01 00:00:00.000`). In order to convert the record time to seconds we are using the [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function three time to extract the hours, the minutes and the seconds from your record date.

To fix the date in your table you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [Date] =  DATEADD(SECOND, DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]) * 3600 + DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) * 60 + DATEPART(SECOND, [Date], '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000');
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I would have to alter all the code in the application...!

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily use dateadd for this, the easy way is adding the time from one column with the datetime of the other column like this:

```
SELECT 
  cast('1899-12-30 16:00:00.000' as time)+
  cast('2015-07-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

Result:

```
2015-07-01 16:00
```

Comment: Interesting, that it is correct, although SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetime,'1899-12-30 16:00:00.000') as float) is negativ!

Thanks!

Comment: why would you ever convert a datetime to a float ? This can always be done with better methods

Comment: I just converted it to check the numeric value.

Comment: how can I implement this in Oracle?

Answer (score -1):

Normally i would always use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for this type of operation.

Hope it helps

Comment: you should not post an answer like this without offering an example. Especially since a DATEADD isn't an easy solution in this example